# Combine multiple screens to one large screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, screen

I have a computer with 3 screens connected to an Nvidia GPU.

If I make a program to fullscreen mode, it only goes fullscreen on one of the screens.
What I try to achieve is, that the **3 separate screens** (1920x1080) **are recognized as one big screen** (5760x1080).

If I start for example Mplayer in fullscreen, it will then go over all 3 screens.
If I go to Nvidia settings tab, it should display me one large screen (5760x1080).

Currently on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with XFCE.

Tried to achieve with

```
xrandr --setmonitor MyMonitorName auto HDMI-0,eDP-1-1,eDP-2-1
```

with no success.

```
arandr
```

did also not help.

Anyone a solution?
Is there another window manager which can handle this?

Comment: You can manually resize each window to extend it across three monitors .

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.
When opening a program via terminal command to launch in fullscreen, I might not have a mouse to do so...

Answer (score 0):

There is only one workaround I figured out so far for video playback over several screens:

- Install KDE plasma
- Go to System Settings => Window Management => KWIN Scripts => enable Video Wall

[image: screenshot of multiview]

Since this is only a workaround (because it relies on using KDE), still looking for the right answer.

Also read a lot about Nvidia Twinview, but was not able to enable it somehow...